# Java delete file function is not working, my file not deleting and not throwing any errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I have java code that supposed to delete my existing file in my device but it does not work I don't why. It keep returning false when I try to use the .delete() function.

Here's my code, I already closed all the buffered and writer but it still not working

```
        File saveFile = new File("save.txt");
        File saveTemp = new File("temp.txt");
        File playerFile = new File(player.username + ".txt");
        String currentLine;
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveTemp, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("save.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            
            while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!currentLine.equals(player.username))
                {
                    pw.println(currentLine);
                }
            }
            
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            fr.close();
            br.close();
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
            
            saveFile.delete();
            playerFile.delete();
            File dump = new File("save.txt");
            saveTemp.renameTo(dump);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I'd suggest using [Files.delete](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-) instead of File.delete.  This has the benefit of throwing an exception on failure.  It won't get your file deleted if it's not being deleted now, but at least you might find out why.  For similar reasons, I'd suggest [Files.move](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) instead of File.renameTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java.io.File` API is **obsolete**. That means it is deprecated (you should stop using it), but, given that it is core API, 'deprecated' as a term specifically used in core means 'sometime somewhat soon, this will not work whatsoever', and `java.io.File` isn't that - it'll work 10 years from now. But you still shouldn't use it. There are fundamental issues to its design that means it's a flawed API and it won't (cannot) be fixed.

One of its many flaws is that it is un-java-like in how it conveys errors to you. Weirdly, most of the `File` API itself **does not** throw exceptions when things go wrong. Instead, it returns wonky things.

For example, `file.list()` returns an empty array if you run that on an empty directory, but returns `null` if it can't do the job (for example, the dir doesn't exist, or it's a file and not a dir, or, the java process doesn't have read rights). Similarly, `delete()` **does not** throw an exception. Instead to indicate failure it returns `false`. This is not only un-java-like, it also means it is **not possible** to know *why* `delete()` doesn't work. Access rights issue? File doesn't exist? Who knows.

The simple conclusion is that you should *always* be checking the return value of anything you do to a `j.i.File` object, but that's taking a shortcut. The true fix is **to stop using it**.

The new API also has problems but far fewer. It's also not obsolete/deprecated-in-the-english-dictionary-sense: This *is* how a state of the art java app should be interacting with files. You find it in the `java.nio.file` package.

Unlike the `j.i.File` API, this one **does** throw exceptions when things go wrong, and those exceptions tell you, both program-checkable (a hierarchy of types, such as `NoSuchFileException` if you want to specifically react to such an issue), and human-checkable, in that the messages of these exceptions explain in english what's wrong.

Secondarily, you MUST close objects-that-represent-system-resources safely and your code does not do that. There's the handy try-with syntax that makes that easy, so let's do that too!

Thirdly, you are flushing-then-closing. This is pointless; `close()` already implies flush, there is no reason to *ever* call flush() before close, it just clutters up your code. In fact, with try-with there's no need to close whatsoever.

Thus:

```
Path tempFile = Paths.get("temp.txt");
Path saveFile = Paths.get("save.txt");
try (
  Writer fw = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFile, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
  BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(saveFile);
  ) {

  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.equals(player.username)) continue;
    fw.write(line);
    fw.write("\n");
  }
}

Files.delete(saveFile);
Files.move(tempFile, saveFile);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how I create a new file with the java.nio.package, because I want to create the new temp file, not getting existing temp.txt file

Comment: The same way you do today.  A `File` is not a file, it's a data structure containing a representation of a file path.  I don't see a strong compulsion to avoid `File` entirely - just don't call its methods that actually do things to the file system.  But note, you don't need a `File` to create a `FileWriter`.

Comment: @ArfurNarf If you treat File as a vehicle for a path and ignore just about every method it has, then..... why not use String? Or if you (correctly) prefer a type that is more descriptive of what it contains, what can File do that Path cannot, other than things you shouldn't be doing with File?

Comment: @nipeng If you want a new temp file, `Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)` ensures it's new (throws if it isn't), and `Files.createTempFile` makes new files, picking random names for you to ensure they are unique.

Comment: Ok, thank you for all the answer I tried it, but using ` Files.createFile(tempFile); ` is fine too. now the problem is I getting the error file is being used by another process, I didnt even open the file

Comment: Are you sure? It's probably your own process. Your example code isn't properly closing resources (use `try(...)` syntax).

Comment: I pretty sure I already terminate all the debug process also I already using the try syntax. The create temp file is working fine but it throws `file is being used by another process` when it reach the `Files.delete`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot "then..... why not use String?" -- In this case, why not, indeed?  I answered from a position of not being able to rewrite all of the vast corpus of code I need to interface with.   Constructing a Path *just* to call toFile on always seems a bit silly.

Comment: @ArfurNarf Obsolete/deprecated-in-the-dictionary-sense doesn't mean "go out and rewrite all usages of it _now_". Merely: An SO answer that advises using that _now_ is wrong, and you shouldn't write new code with that stuff. There's nothing wrong with using `.toPath()` / `toFile()` to paper over aged API that doesn't take Path objects yet.

Comment: @nipeng paste the _complete_ code. The error isn't lying to you - some process has it open. It is exceedingly likely it's your code.

Comment: Sorry for the late response
Here's my code:
`Path tempFile = Paths.get("temp.txt"); try {
   Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFile, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  } Path saveFile = Paths.get("save.txt");
  Path playerFile = Paths.get(player.username + ".txt");`

The rest is the same try catch code that you provided

Comment: I already figured it out, Thank you

Comment: @nipeng That code you just pasted in the comment 4 hours ago __does not__ use try-with, which is exactly what I told you is the likely explanation. Start using try-with.