# Java: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process when deleting file

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to delete some file in my device but I keep getting throws that the file is being used in another process. I'm pretty sure I already terminate all the debug process and not opening any file expect my Eclipse IDE, which I did not open the file in the IDE either.

Here's my code:

```java
Path tempFile = Paths.get("temp.txt");
try {
    Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFile, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
Path saveFile = Paths.get("save.txt");
Path playerFile = Paths.get(player.username + ".txt");
try (
        Writer fw = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFile, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(saveFile);
    ) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equals(player.username))
            continue;
        fw.write(line);
        fw.write("\n");
    }
    Files.delete(saveFile);
    Files.delete(playerFile);
    Files.move(tempFile, saveFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error is thrown when I reach the `Files.delete(saveFile)` line.

Comment: It will give some error `Unhandled exception type IOException` If I put it outside after the `catch` block and if I create another `try catch` after the `catch` it still return the same error

Comment: Looks like you didn't copy your answer here: [Java delete file function is not working, my file not deleting and not throwing any errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75966704/java-delete-file-function-is-not-working-my-file-not-deleting-and-not-throwing)

Comment: Move the `Files.delete` and `Files.move` outside the try-with-resources, so that both the reader and the writer are already closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete the file until it is closed and it is closed after exiting the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block.

I suggest using a nested `try`.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class MyGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path tempFile = Paths.get("temp.txt");
        Path saveFile = Paths.get("save.txt");
        Path playerFile = Paths.get(player.username + ".txt");
        try {
            try (Writer fw = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFile,
                                                     StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                     StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                 BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(saveFile)) {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.equals(player.username))
                        continue;
                    fw.write(line);
                    fw.write("\n");
                }
            }
            Files.delete(saveFile);
            Files.delete(playerFile);
            Files.move(tempFile, saveFile);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is no need to explicitly create the "temp" file before writing to it. Besides which [CREATE_NEW](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#CREATE_NEW) will throw an exception if the "temp" file already exists and I assume that this is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the writer which builds the file. Until it is closed, process consider the file as opened, so it wont allow you to delete

Comment: I think I already close it using the AutoClosable in the `try catch` block. I already try close it manually `fw.close()` and `br.close()`, It still return the same problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).